# Struggling to Populate JavaFX TableView with SQLite data

Tags: sqlite, javafx, tableview

I am trying to get data from an SQLite database into a JavaFX TableView object and have got as far as the rows being added but the actual data is not showing. I have looked everywhere to try and understand how to do this but am relatively new to Java. Here is the code if someone could take a look and help out. The code is, admittedly, a bit messy because I have tried all sorts to get it working. Thanks in advance...

```
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.stage.WindowEvent;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.MenuBar;
import javafx.scene.control.MenuItem;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.control.TitledPane;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;

public class MasterController {
    Stage stage = new Stage();
    @FXML
    private ResourceBundle resources;

    @FXML
    private URL location;

    @FXML
    private TitledPane titledPane;

    @FXML
    private BorderPane borderPane;

    @FXML
    private TableView tableViewId;

    @FXML
    private MenuBar mainMenuId;

    @FXML
    private MenuItem closeId;

    @FXML
    private MenuItem deleteId;

    @FXML
    private MenuItem helpId;

    @FXML
    private Label searchLabelId;

    @FXML
    private TextField searchId;

    @FXML
    private Button goId;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Music, String> artistColId;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Music, String> titleColId;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Music, String> albumColId;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Music, String> genreColId;

    @FXML
    void closeClicked(ActionEvent event) {

    }

    @FXML
    void deleteClicked(ActionEvent event) {

    }

    @FXML
    void goClicked(MouseEvent event) {

    }

    @FXML
    void helpClicked(ActionEvent event) {

    }

    @FXML
    void initialize() {
        assert titledPane != null : "fx:id=\"titledPane\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'Untitled'.";
        assert borderPane != null : "fx:id=\"borderPane\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'Untitled'.";
        assert mainMenuId != null : "fx:id=\"mainMenuId\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'Untitled'.";
        assert closeId != null : "fx:id=\"closeId\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'Untitled'.";
        assert deleteId != null : "fx:id=\"deleteId\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'Untitled'.";
        assert helpId != null : "fx:id=\"helpId\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'Untitled'.";
        assert searchLabelId != null : "fx:id=\"searchLabelId\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'Untitled'.";
        assert searchId != null : "fx:id=\"searchId\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'Untitled'.";
        assert goId != null : "fx:id=\"goId\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'Untitled'.";
        assert tableViewId != null : "fx:id=\"tableViewId\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'Untitled'.";
        assert artistColId != null : "fx:id=\"artistColId\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'Untitled'.";
        assert titleColId != null : "fx:id=\"titleColId\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'Untitled'.";
        assert albumColId != null : "fx:id=\"albumColId\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'Untitled'.";
        assert genreColId != null : "fx:id=\"genreColId\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'Untitled'.";

    }

        public void prepareStageEvents(Stage stage)
    {
        System.out.println("Preparing stage events...");

        this.stage = stage;
        ObservableList<Music> targetData = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        System.out.println(targetData);
        tableViewId.setItems(Music.showAll());
        stage.setOnCloseRequest(new EventHandler<WindowEvent>() {
                public void handle(WindowEvent we) {
                    System.out.println("Close button was clicked!");
                    Application.terminate();
                }
            });
    }   
}
```

And here is the Music class code

```
import java.util.List;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;

public class Music{
    public int trackId;
    public String title;
    public String artist;
    public String album;
    public String genre;

    public Music(int trackId, String title, String artist, String album, String genre){
        this.trackId = trackId;
        this.title = title;
        this.artist = artist;
        this.album = album;
        this.genre = genre;
    }

    @Override public String toString()
    {
        return trackId + "\t" + title + "\t" + artist + "\t" + album + "\t" + genre;
    }

    public static ObservableList<Music> showAll(){
        PreparedStatement statement = Application.database.newStatement("select tracks.TrackId, tracks.Title, artist.ArtistName, album.albumTitle, album.albumGenre from tracks inner join artist on tracks.artistId = artist.artistId left outer join album on tracks.albumId = album.albumId");
        ObservableList<Music> musicData = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        if (statement != null)      // Assuming the statement correctly initated...
        {
            ResultSet results = Application.database.runQuery(statement);       // ...run the query!

            if (results != null)        // If some results are returned from the query...
            {
                try {                               // ...add each one to the list.
                    while (results.next()) {                                               
                        musicData.add(new Music(results.getInt("TrackId"), results.getString("Title"), results.getString("ArtistName"), results.getString("albumTitle"), results.getString("albumGenre")));
                    }
                }
                catch (SQLException resultsexception)       // Catch any error processing the results.
                {
                    System.out.println("Database result processing error: " + resultsexception.getMessage());
                }
            }
        }
        return musicData;
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure whether or not you are setting the `cellValueFactory` in the FXML file, but if you are, you presumably are using a `PropertyValueFactory`, and the model class `Music` has no accessor (`getXXX`) methods for that to see. Show the `cellValueFactory`, if you have them; otherwise you need to define them. See [any intro tutorial](http://code.makery.ch/library/javafx-8-tutorial/part2/) on table view.

Comment: Thank you for getting back to me. In the end I created the scene from scratch and imported the data that way which does use the .SetCellFactory values to the corresponding field names in the recordset. The problem was trying to make solutions I've found fit with the way I've coded rather than the other way around. Now that it's working I can try again with my original version.

Comment: You mean `setCellValueFactory`, right, not `setCellFactory`?

Comment: That's the one. As it turns out there were a few things I hadn't done like assigning the Music object name to the column references. All in all it's been an experience trying to do something that seemed like it should be easy enough to do. I've only been dabbling with Java for a year or so and so am still trying to get used to needing different libraries for different tasks. Long story short I now have the original project working.